# The Jewish name "Isser"

Tags: names

What is the source of the name Isser? On what Yiddish, Hebrew or Jewish term - if any - is it based?

Comment: איסור איטלקי...

Answer (score 2):

[This book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0824602951) explains that Isser is a variant of the name *Yisrael*, citing a tradition of dropping God's name from the name itself - like Eliyahu becoming Elya, for example.

Comment: Elya is often spelled _Aleph_-_lamed_-_Yud_ with an apostrophe to avoid the _Yud_-_Hei_ conjunction (as appears also in the last letters of Eliyahu). Don't shoot the messenger; I didn't say I agreed with it, only that that's the rationale presented.

Comment: This is supported by such names as Yisrael Isserlin (the Terumas HaDeshen), see https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%A8%D7%9C%D7%9F#.D7.AA.D7.95.D7.9C.D7.93.D7.95.D7.AA.D7.99.D7.95

Answer (score 2):

As per the sefer Zocher Ha'bris  (24-17) and Sefer Ha'bris (page 318-22) it appears that the name Isser is actually not a variant of Yisroel but it is pshuto ki'mashma'o and it means "prohibition." Apparently whenever an unmarried girl gave birth to a boy, the newborn was named Issur. Maybe later on, in order to whitewash the family history, the idea of it being a variant of Yisroel was created.

Comment: Very interesting, and thanks for the source. I will look it up later.